# ReadingProgress Of a backup being uploaded

Tags: sql-server, .net-3.5

Hello I am using following code to restore the database in my program.

sqlcmd = New SqlCommand("Restore Database  db1 From Disk = '" & txtFileName.Text & "' with replace")
            sqlcmd.Connection = con
            sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

This code is working perfectly but i want to show a progress bar based on the progress of Restoring process. How could i do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you are running this against SQL 2005 or later, you can use the following query to monitor the status of the restore action.

```
SELECT
    command, start_time, percent_complete,
    CAST(((DATEDIFF(s,start_time,GetDate()))/3600) as varchar) + ' hour(s), '
        + CAST((DATEDIFF(s,start_time,GetDate())%3600)/60 as varchar) + 'min, '
        + CAST((DATEDIFF(s,start_time,GetDate())%60) as varchar) + ' sec' as running_time,
    CAST((estimated_completion_time/3600000) as varchar) + ' hour(s), '
        + CAST((estimated_completion_time %3600000)/60000 as varchar) + 'min, '
        + CAST((estimated_completion_time %60000)/1000 as varchar) + ' sec' as est_time_to_go,
    dateadd(second,estimated_completion_time/1000, getdate()) as est_completion_time, s.text
FROM 
    sys.dm_exec_requests r
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle) s
WHERE 
    r.command in ('RESTORE DATABASE', 'BACKUP DATABASE', 'RESTORE LOG', 'BACKUP LOG', 'DBCC TABLE CHECK')
```

You can tweak the values in the WHERE clause to control the actions for which the status will be returned.

Comment: Confirmed still works on SQL 2013. Thanks so much! Had a very long-running restore to a network drive on a slow upload, used this to see if it would be done anytime soon or if I had to cancel it to continue another day.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to exactly know the size of backup file. What you can do is before running backup command, find out the size of the database and you can approximately guess that 1GB may take 1 second for backup and show the progress bar accordingly